# Conflict in dateadd operation in SQL2016 but not 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I found a difference in behaviour of adding `date` and `datetime` types in SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2016.
For the query:

```
select convert(date,getdate())+getdate()
```

I get error in SQL2016:

> The data types date and datetime are incompatible in the add operator.

In 2012 it returns no error, just corect sum of dates.
What is the reason of such behaviour?

Comment: What version of 2012 are you using? It doesn't work on mine in any version. You shouldn't use lazy date math anyway. You should use DATEADD. Seriously what kind of logic is the current date plus the current date anyway? Logically it makes no sense. It will run in 2008R2 but the return is bizarre regardless.

Comment: Which was and is logical nonsense. At some point MS decided that the addition operator would not support newer datatypes but would continue backward compatibility support for datetime. Evolve.

Comment: It  was only example, DATEADD is obviousely better but i found that and wonder why is happend  SQL2012 version is 11.0.6020.0 and 2016 is 13.0.4001.0

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2012, the operators were (silently?) changed to disallow mismatched types being added or subtracted. It apparently relates to the SQL Server 2008 ability to store Date and Time separately. You will need to cast to a common type (e.g. cast to date then to datetime).

Seems like a pretty large breaking change to me, but apparently Microsoft felt is was needed.